# ADMIN$ share giving unspecified error (no credential prompt)

Tags: network-share

I've been battling a recent issue between Server 2022 (source machine on WORKGROUP) and Server 2016 (destination machine on DOMAIN). My application (Veeam VBR) needs access to the destinations ADMIN$ share in order to deploy some software. The issue is seemingly with only one Server 2016 machine which is odd since everything on the domain is controlled with group policy.

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName destination -port 445
```

The test above from source to destination is successful. However as soon as I open up explorer.exe and type \destination\admin$ I'm presented with an unspecified error (0x80004005). I can resolve the destination by DNS using "destination" or "destination.domain.local" with success.

Why am I not being prompted for credentials when attempting to access the ADMIN$ on the source when every other machine prompts me? In an attempt to "trick" the systems I opened Windows Credential Manager and added a new credential for the destination server. Then opened a new explorer.exe window and successfully opened the ADMIN$. Thinking my problem was now resolved I attempted the application deployment but receive an error (The network path was not found (ERROR_BAD_NETPATH).

What could possibly be causing this?